# How to prevent safari from scroll-snapping outside container's children?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, safari

In Chrome it works beautifully:

[image]

However in Safari it snaps before the first item and after the last item:

[image]

Here's a [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/tixojiw/edit?html,output)

```css
  container {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 50%;
    padding-right: 50%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
    scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
  }
  child {
    display: inline-block;
    background: green;
    margin: 0 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20vw;
    scroll-snap-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<container>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
  <child></child>
</container>
```